# NSImage to NSData, then to UIImage

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, uiimage, nsimage

I am creating a plist from my OSX app that contains some images. I am writing the image by :

```
[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.someImage]
```

Then I am using this plist file as a template for iOS app, but here I can't convert the file to `UIImage` and neither to `NSImage`(as this is only for OSX).

I am getting this error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: '***
>   -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:]: cannot decode object of class (NSImage)'

Please suggest me a way to perform the above.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**OS X:**
Instead of using `NSKeyedArchiver` to convert an `NSImage` to `NSData`, use `NSImage`'s [`TIFFRepresentation`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSImage/TIFFRepresentation) method:

```
NSData *imageData = [self.someImage TIFFRepresentation];
// save imageData to file
```

**iOS:**
Read the image data from the file, then convert it to a UIImage using UIImage's [`+imageWithData:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageWithData:) convenience constructor:

```
NSData *imageData = ...; // load imageData from file
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: imageData];
```

Comment: I think you want `TIFFRepresentation` here

Comment: 2024: We are getting into era of large images and compression is inevitable. Use TIFFRepresentationUsingCompression:factor: Also is better to check for underlying representation and use pdf/svg vector data

Answer (score 5):

You need to create a `NSBitmapImageRep` and then save that, then read the `NSData` to `UIImage` with `+[UIImage imageWithData:]`:

First in OS X, save the data:

```
NSString *filepath;
NSBitmapImageRep *imageRep = [NSBitmapImageRep imageRepWithContentsOfFile:filepath];

NSData *data = [imageRep representationUsingType:NSPNGFileType properties:nil];
// Save the data
```

You could also use [`imageRepWithData:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSBitmapImageRep_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSBitmapImageRep/imageRepWithData:) if you have `NSData` of the image already - the above will load it from a file (like you can [also](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000344-initWithContentsOfFile_) do with `NSImage`).

Then in iOS:

```
NSData *data; // Load from a file
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSBitmapImageRep_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Bitmap_image_properties) for the other allowed keys for the dictionary in `representationUsingType:properties:`.

Comment: UIImagePNGRepresentation() is being used incorrectly in the above code: The function is meant for converting a UIImage instance into an NSData object, not for converting NSData into a UIImage. See: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIImagePNGRepresentation

Answer (score -1):

### macOS

I found using TIFFRepresentation gave me tiny 15x15 images (I was trying to resize an SF Symbol ([NSImage imageWithSystemSymbolName](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsimage/3622472-imagewithsystemsymbolname?language=objc)). Here's an alternative method to get an NSBitmapImageRep and its bytes [based on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38442746/79125):

```
NSData* ImageToData(NSImage *image, int width, int height)
{
    // Build image rep with desired size.
    NSSize size = NSMakeSize(width, height);
    NSBitmapImageRep *rep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc]
        initWithBitmapDataPlanes:NULL
                      pixelsWide:size.width
                      pixelsHigh:size.height
                   bitsPerSample:8
                 samplesPerPixel:4
                        hasAlpha:YES
                        isPlanar:NO
                  colorSpaceName:NSCalibratedRGBColorSpace
                     bytesPerRow:0
                    bitsPerPixel:0];
    rep.size = size;

    [NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];
    [NSGraphicsContext setCurrentContext:[NSGraphicsContext graphicsContextWithBitmapImageRep:rep]];
    [image drawInRect:NSMakeRect(0, 0, size.width, size.height) fromRect:NSZeroRect operation:NSCompositingOperationCopy fraction:1.0];
    [NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState];

    if (rep == nil)
    {
        return nil;
    }
    // Passing nil gives a warning but seems to work okay.
    return [rep representationUsingType:NSBitmapImageFileTypePNG properties:nil];
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't archive image. It creates resized copy. If you need to rasterize vector NSImageRep at higher resolution use let cgImage = imageRep.cgImage(forProposedRect: &proposedRect, context: nil, hints: [:])  https://stackoverflow.com/a/78002831/2648673

Comment: Apple is using also following PRIVATE hints in webkit NSImageHintSymbolFont : [NSFont systemFontOfSize:32], NSImageHintSymbolScale : @(NSImageSymbolScaleMedium). You should be good without them as well. https://github.com/WebKit/WebKit/blob/04d4979c9e1d766b1ad11eac36f7593ee8bb268d/Source/WebCore/rendering/mac/RenderThemeMac.mm#L1352

Answer (score -3):

You can convert an NSImage into NSData using the apple built-in API as follows:

```
UIImage *MyImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"WhateverDir/MyImage.png"];
NSData *MyImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(MyImage);
```

Comment: You're converting UIImage here (i.e. iOS) not NSImage (i.e. OS X)