# Rendering the same image with different sizes

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsimage

I have bunch of images in my assets. What I am trying to do is render the image in status bar of OSX as following:

```
let icon = NSImage(named: "statusIcon")
icon?.size = NSSize.init(width: 18, height: 18)

icon?.template = true
statusItem.image = icon
statusItem.menu = statusMenu
```

and also using it in one of my view which opens:

```
self.dayIcon.image = NSImage(named: "statusIcon")
```

The problem is as soon as I set the status bar image, the image in the view also changes, i.e. both the color and the size(changes to 18x18)

I have tried using

```
icon?.cacheMode = NSImageCacheMode.Never
```

but there is no effect.

Is this how it is supposed to be? Can I not use the same image and render it differently at different places. They are both different `NSImage` instances.

Comment: Try setting NSImage template property to false

Comment: template is needed for setting the status icon

Comment: I think you're correct in thinking that you're getting a cached version. However, the `cacheMode` property is only to do with the actual drawing. Have you tried making an explicit copy of the image? `icon = icon.copy()`

Comment: Have you tried setting the image name to something else? (i.e. `icon.setName("statusIconResized")` )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> They are both different `NSImage` instance.

They are not, and that is, indeed, your problem.

+[NSImage imageNamed:] may return an existing cached instance of the image.

If you want to change the size on the image without affecting anyone else who may be holding a reference, make a copy of it. The copy of the NSImage is lightweight - it doesn't duplicate the underlying image representations which hold the rendering (bitmap, in the PNG case) data.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose that you need to resize image first. For doing that you may use different ways. For example you can write extension for NSImage class. For example [Resize NSImage in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30422317/436694)

Comment: Also I sugest you to read nice article about status bar icons sizing: https://alastairs-place.net/blog/2013/07/23/nsstatusitem-what-size-should-your-icon-be/